# Extjs - Set focus field in panel

Tags: extjs, focus, panel, extjs4.1

I define a panel extend Ext.form.Panel with alias is: "example".

and in my viewport i init xtype = 'example' for my east.

I want when i collapse that panel (example) then my first field (datefield) will focus

I try some below code but not working

```
//1. not working
,listeners: {
     afterrender: function(field) {
         field.focus(true, 100);
     }
}
//2. not working
Ext.getCmp('myDatefieldId').focus(true, 20);
```

How can i do that thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you provide a little bit more information?
Do you use Controllers (mvc-pattern?)
If yes, you could try to handle the focussing in the controller.

We have got two DateFields in our center and focussing via
**Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=dtf-faelligkeit-ab]')[0].focus()**
seems to work perfect (tested with chrome developer console)

In my viewport I added a collapse-Listener:

```
region: 'east',
                layout: 'border',
                id: 'viewport-east-todo-panel',
                title: 'Todo - Detailansicht',
                labelWidth: 100,
                collapsible: true,
                collapsed: true,
                split: true,
                width: 340,
                minSize: 340,
                maxSize: 400,
                items: [
                    {
                        region: 'center',
                        xtype: 'main.todo.TodoDetails'
                    }
                ]
                ,
                listeners: {
                    collapse: function () {
                        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=dtf-faelligkeit-ab]')[0].focus();
                    }
                }
```

In the collapse-Listener, I focus the datefield (itemID: 'dtf-faelligkeit-ab').

Hope I could help you

Comment: thank u so much. I using my panel have collapsed: true and i using expand: function (p, eOpts ){} with my 2nd above code and it working. But i don't know why my 1st above code not working :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you on your first code problem. I'm quite an extjs-rookie and dealing with events means always a new problem for me. There's hopefully someone out there reading your question and knowing how to deal with it. Good luck ;)